# iOS5 problems with old applications

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5

I need advice on what to do.

I have several applications on App store and they are all tested and fully functional for all previous iOS's. But now when I update my device to iOS5 some of them began to crash unexpectedly on alert view item that ask for connecting to internet and show map with current location.

I am not that experienced in development so need some advice what to do? I supposed that with final version of iOS5 these things will be fixed by itself or not.

Thanks.

OK I have torned zombies and found method that makes problems.

```
    - (void) alertView: (UIAlertView*) alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSLog(@" Button PRESSED: %d", buttonIndex);
    [alertView release];



    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        BOOL noConnectionAvailable = NO;
        BOOL hasParentalLimit = NO;

        switch (lastSelectedItem.itemType) {
            case RestaurantItemTypeAddress : {
                if ([NetworkHelper connectedToNetwork] == YES) {
                    AddressController *mapController = [[AddressController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddressController" bundle:nil restaurant:restaurant];
                    mapController.title = restaurant.res_title;
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapController animated:YES];
                    [mapController release];
                } else 
                    noConnectionAvailable = YES;

                break;
            }
            case RestaurantItemTypeReservationEmail : {
                if ([NetworkHelper connectedToNetwork] == YES) {
                    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
                    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

                    [picker setSubject:@"Reservation"];
                    // Set up recipients
                    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:lastSelectedItem.itemTextContent];             
                    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

                    // Fill out the email body text
                    NSString *emailBody = @"";
                    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

                    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
                    [picker release];

                    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:lastSelectedIndexPath animated:YES];
                } else 
                    noConnectionAvailable = YES;

                break;
            }
            case RestaurantItemTypeReservationForm : {
                if ([NetworkHelper connectedToNetwork] == YES) {
                    if ([NetworkHelper canOpenUrl:lastSelectedItem.itemTextContent]) {
                        WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil urlStr:lastSelectedItem.itemTextContent];
                        wvc.title = restaurant.res_title;
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:wvc animated:YES];
                        [wvc release];
                    } else hasParentalLimit = YES;
                } else
                    noConnectionAvailable = YES;

                break;
            }
            case RestaurantItemTypeWeb : {
                if ([NetworkHelper connectedToNetwork] == YES) {
                    if ([NetworkHelper canOpenUrl:lastSelectedItem.itemTextContent]) {
                        WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil urlStr:lastSelectedItem.itemText];
                        wvc.title = restaurant.res_title;
                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:wvc animated:YES];
                        [wvc release];
                    } else hasParentalLimit = YES;
                } else
                    noConnectionAvailable = YES;

                break;
            }

        }

        if (noConnectionAvailable == YES) {
            UIAlertView* newAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Jesolo Official Guide" 
                                                               message:@"Nessuna connessione disponibile." 
                                                              delegate:self 
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [newAlert show]; 
        }

        if (hasParentalLimit == YES) {
            UIAlertView* newAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Jesolo Official Guide" 
                                                               message:@"Navigazione su Web non consentita." 
                                                              delegate:self 
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [newAlert show];

        }

    }

    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:lastSelectedIndexPath animated:NO];

}
```

The log is different on iOS4 and iOS5.
On iOS5 it said:

```
 2011-11-04 16:26:28.550 Jesolo-EN[5693:207]  Button PRESSED: 1
2011-11-04 16:26:28.776 Jesolo-EN[5693:207] *** -[NSIndexPath isEqual:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xe6b6fc0
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame.
(gdb)
```

and on iOS4 said:

```
2011-11-04 16:28:08.087 Jesolo-EN[5859:207]  Button PRESSED: 1
2011-11-04 16:28:08.162 Jesolo-EN[5859:207] *** -[UIAlertView release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x78c4940
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

I understand that i release data before i use them but when I run app without enabled zombies it work fine on iOS4 and on iOS5 it run one time and then 10 times crash.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have no other option than to test again and correct the problem. Find where the problem originates and solve it. It will most likely not be fixed in the final version.

Comment: all my apps have problem on switching views when I have some drown  map divided in sectors. When I click on sector it crashes. don't have any idea how to fix this :(

Comment: +1 for simpleBob's comment. And with the information provided, it's pretty hard to see what the problem might be. This might be useful: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: If there are problems during the betas you should raise bug reports -- that's kind of the point of beta releases. You'll need to be more specific with your question before you're likely to get a good response. Where is the code crashing? Which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am finding that references to ivars that previously worked are now needing to be referenced as self.ivar. Perhaps your reference to managedObjectContext should instead be self.managedObjectContext?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very much sure about this but you can try this also..

```
Click on your **project**->go to **info**-> go to **build** section-> in that go to **Deployment** section->then **IOS deployment** section choose the **deployment target to IOS 5** or latest and save and run...
```

Hope it may help you... :)

Answer (score 0):

OK I manage to find solution.

Somehow iOS5 detect some release of objects that doest'n exist in iOS4 and I tried to find them but gave up.

Instead of that I turn on ARC and comment all release and dealloc and my app is doing really fine. I get impression that now it works even faster. Hope this will help somebody...